# Cannot access static member variable from class in array

Tags: php, class, oop, static, member

I am trying to access a static class member variable in an array.

My Code (index.php):

```
<?php

class Foo
{
    public static $staticVar = 'test';
}

class Bar
{
    public $someArray = array(
        Foo::$staticVar
    );
}

$cls = new Bar();

var_dump($cls->someArray);

?>
```

On PHP-7.0 I get this error:

> PHP Fatal error: Constant expression contains invalid operations in
>   /var/www/html/index.php on line 12

On PHP-5.6 I get this error:

> PHP Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '$staticVar' (T_VARIABLE),
>   expecting identifier (T_STRING) or class (T_CLASS) in
>   /var/www/html/index.php on line 11

I just want to have the string "test" in my array.

It´s strange that when I 'echo' out the variable it works as expected:

```
echo Foo::$staticVar // prints 'test'
```

I´m new to PHP and I can´t figure out what I´m doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, you can't refer to another variable or class in the initial declaration of a class property. It's just a limitation of the language as it stands. The general workaround is to initialise the property in the constructor, e.g.

```
class Bar
{
    public $someArray = array();

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->someArray = array(
            Foo::$staticVar
        );
    }
}
```

On a vaguely related note, PHP 5.6 did at least make some vague headway in allowing you to define constants as basic expressions, see https://3v4l.org/6TDZV

Comment: So is there any workaround to get the string into the array? I´m just curious how to get rid of that error and/or make it more the 'php way'.

Comment: @hecaex Added an example to the answer